# Successfully execute a QT application build with codeblocks on windows

Tags: qt, codeblocks

For some reason, I am forced to create a distribution of my application (originally developed on windows with visual studio) running on a Linux server. But even the smallest step towards Linux is full of pain because nothing seems to work anymore. I'm currently trying to transfer my project to the IDE codeblocks on Windows because I want to build the project with GCC first. If I succeed, I am probably able to copy and paste the project on a Linux machine and simply rebuild it.
Unfortunately, I am not able to run a Qt HelloWorld project build with MinGW and Codeblocks. I followed these instructions setting up the project:
http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=23059.0

and besides:

http://www.kerrywong.com/2008/07/12/codeblocks-settings-for-qt-development/

There is no problem during the build. However, if I try to execute the application, I immediately get a runtime error "Cannot start the application (0xc0000...7b)"

So I also tried to deploy Qt for windows applications without any effect. What am I missing?

cmd: "C:\Qt\5.11.2\mingw53_32\bin\windeployqt.exe" "C:\Users\Steph\ownCloud\Codeblocks\cb_fail\bin\Debug\cb_fail.exe"

code:

```
#include <QString>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QString smth = "Hello Qt";
    std::cout << smth.toStdString();

}
```

Codeblocks compiler settings
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Qt Creator is not to blame. I develop everything in Linux Ubuntu and then port to Windows. And Qt Creator is everywhere. If you want to compile with GCC on Windows then don't abandon Creator but use MingW GCC compiler and then you could get precompiled Qt for that (absolutely sure) and use same project with Qt Creator with only target Qt differing. All after you install appropriate MingW. I would not even do that but immediately switch to Linux Ubuntu with everything but not CodeBlocks.

Comment: I will never switch to Linux, this taste is enough for me. The Creator could actually be an alternative, I had forgotten about it. Since it is very intrusive under Windows, but visual studio is the much better IDE even for developing Qt projects, I muted it. I will try to compile a Qt project within the creator utilizing MinGW.

Comment: Qt creator worked fine. tý

Comment: Ubuntu 20 was unable to run on my SSD. It is broken because Ubuntu said so. Windows run without any problem. So I got a new SSD and installed Ubuntu 20 + Qt Creator 5 with Qt 5.15. Nothing is working "out-of-the-box". The default clang code model is unable to run with Qt Code (why is this even an option). IGL was not installed, and Qt Creator could not auto-detect its own qmake executable. After an hour, I successfully build and run a Qt Creator example project. Every bit of Qt code is highlighted as a syntax error. After all, this is not an option.

Comment: I dunno. We use gcc. All works all the time. More people around me work on Linux.

Comment: My colleagues, who are also ubuntu fans, were also perplexed by the errors that occurred. The first experiments on Windows to create a .pro with VS and open it with Qt Creator were quite successful. However, I could not compile as my MinGW32 does not provide access to std::variant. In the end I have no other choice than to keep trying on the Linux system. Maybe another compiler will help fixing the Qt creator issues.